# How to get value of a matrix from every row with the index generated by argmax in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I considered gather_nd, but it seemed that gather_nd need a index like [[0,..],[1,..],[2,..]] to get value from every row, and argmax just generated the 1-dimension indexes tensor, it seems that I have to run the argmax, get the narray, use for-loop to add the range index and then feed that into the graph again. I want to know is there any method that can directly get the result?

Comment: Welcome to Data Science SE! Could you maybe post some code?